# Is the Falcon Heavy as loud as the Space Shuttle or Saturn V?

Tags: launch, spacex, space-shuttle, falcon-heavy, sound

Is the Falcon Heavy Rocket as loud as the older Saturn V and Space Shuttles?

I have read that Saturn V and the Space Shuttle were within a few decibels of each other. The newer Shuttle was slightly quieter than the older Saturn V. How does Falcon Heavy compare?

Comment: The sound of the Space Shuttle was different to Saturn V due to the non constant combustion within the boosters. There was a lot of vibration and shaking caused by the boosters. After separation the flight was very smooth.

Comment: We should have a better idea on Feb 6, 2018!  Assuming they launch on time.  Also we should get 4 sonic booms from the landings. ( 2 per stage ).

Comment: I wondered if I was asking too soon. We watched the Falcon Heavy engine test video stream and wondered if sound levels was one of the factors they measure.

Comment: Can't we assume that a FH is just three times F9 and hence 4.8 dB louder? This is assuming there are no coherence effects, no resonances and sound suppression works equally well. I don't have number for the F9 though.

Comment: "within a few decibels" can still mean a big difference in sound as they're measured on a logarithmic scale. A 3dB change means a doubling in sound intensity.

Comment: Any chance SpaceX or a third party checked the volume today?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Expected noise levels can be found in the [environmental assessment](http://www.dtic.mil/dtic/tr/fulltext/u2/a612280.pdf).

For Falcon 9: 156.1 ±  4.9 dB (unweighted) at 125 ft.
For Falcon Heavy: 160.9 ±  4.9 dB (unweighted) at 125 ft.

So asdfex's comment is in line with what SpaceX expects/has calculated. Now this is a 2011 study, after the first v1.0 launch but predating the various upgrades to the F9. I haven't found a more recent environmental assessment.

The Falcon 9 [user manual](https://spacex.com/sites/spacex/files/falcon_9_users_guide_rev_2.0.pdf) lists noise levels inside the payload fairing of up to 131.4 dB.

Answer (score 4):

Real data will not be available for Falcon Heavy until the first launch, scheduled for February 2018. [Noise levels for Falcon Heavy are *estimated* to be below the NASA Space Launch System (SLS)](https://www.faa.gov/about/office_org/headquarters_offices/ast/environmental/nepa_docs/review/launch/media/FAA_FONSI_SpaceX_Falcon_Ops-LC_39A-final.pdf) which produces more thrust. The SLS is expected to be 130 decibels at the launch site.

[The Space Shuttle was louder at 180 dB](https://www.nasa.gov/audience/forstudents/9-12/features/F_Preventing_Fires_on_the_Launchpad.html) at launch, even with the aid of a [Sound Suppression System installed on Pad 39-A](https://www.nasa.gov/mission_pages/shuttle/launch/sound-suppression-system.html) during the 1980s.

The Saturn V predated this suppression system. [Early engine tests reached as high as 211 decibels.](https://history.nasa.gov/SP-4310/ch7.htm)

Comment: It is surprisingly difficult to find accurate data on Space Shuttle and Saturn V decibel levels...

Comment: That's 180 dB "in the payload bay", not outside.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. That seems like an incredible force on the payload. I would love a more accurate reference if I can find one.

Comment: I don't have the reputation to leave a comment, but in response to Dan, I used a decibel meter at several different locations during shuttle launches. Press Site, Banana Creek Site, VAB roof, and never saw more than 122 dB. I don't have any data on Falcon but I would expect it to be not quite as loud as shuttle was.